# was waiting or waited

Tags: past-tense

The hunter **waited** silent and motionless beside a breathing hole where he had seen  a seal the day before

why not **was waiting** as the wait is not completed, the seal has not been there yet

englishlab.net/hp/quiz28_mixed_tenses_4_active_passive_story.htm

Comment: Both verbs are past tense. Why do you think the hunter is still waiting, regardless of the seal's presence?

Comment: Because he wanted to kill him, so he was waiting to see him

Comment: Yes, he wanted (past tense) to kill the seal he had seen before, so he **waited** (past tense). Or his wait was extended during the past, so he **was waiting** (also past tense). What the tenses don't tell you is what the hunter is doing now in the present.

Comment: may be past simple  is used as it was an habitual action  for a hunter in the past

Comment: Good observation. The simple past for habitual action requires some semantic context -- either an *adverbial clue* or an action that by its nature is **repeated or continual**: "I walked to school *every day*" or "I **pined** for my lost love." Grammatical indication arises from the auxiliary verb *would* ("The hunter *would* wait....") or the idiomatic *used to* ("The hunter *used to* wait....") In any case, the action, repeated or not, is still confined to the past.